# Problems with Fixed effects panel data

Tags: r, panel-data, plm

I am trying to run a regression with a panel data from the Michigan Consumers Survey. It is the first time I am using panel data on R so I am not very aware of the package "plm" that is needed. I am setting my panel data for fixed effects on individuals (CASEID) and time (YYYY):

```
Michigan_panel <- pdata.frame(Michigan_survey, index = c("CASEID", "YYYY"))
```

Then I am using the following regression:

```
mod_1 <- plm(data = Michigan_panel, ICS ~  ICE + PX1Q2 +  RATEX + ZLB + INCOME + AGE + EDUC + MARRY + SEX + AGE_sq, model = "within")
```

However R is showing me the following error:

```
> mod_1 <- plm(data = Michigan_panel, ICS ~  ICE + PX1Q2 +  RATEX + ZLB + INCOME + AGE + EDUC + MARRY + SEX + AGE_sq, model = "within")
Error in plm.fit(data, model, effect, random.method, random.models, random.dfcor,  : 
  empty model
```

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Use `plm` with the correct order of arguments, i.e., put the formula first and then the data (also, you may want to have a look at the package's vignettes which have examples how to use the function).

Answer (score 0):

Could you give the link where is this specific survey? I found various dataset with this data name.
I suspect (only suspect),  you data isn't  panel data, please check the CASEID variable.

Changing the order between formula and data in `plm` won't be solve your problem.

.

Answer (score -1):

I think the error come when you write the model. Your solution is this:

```
mod_1 <- plm(data = Michigan_panel, ICS ~  ICE + PX1Q2 +  RATEX + ZLB + INCOME + AGE + EDUC + MARRY + SEX + AGE_sq, model = "within")
```

In my view, you have to specify indexes in the formula, and follow the order of the plm package. I would like to write your formula as follows:

```
 mod_1 <- plm(ICS ~  ICE + PX1Q2 +  RATEX + ZLB + INCOME + AGE + EDUC + MARRY + SEX + AGE_sq, 
data = Michigan_panel,
index= c("CASEID", "YYYY"),
model = "within")
```

**1. Different Approach**

From my knowledge we can also code this formula in a more elegant format.

```
library(plm)
Michigan_panel <- pdata.frame(Michigan_survey, index = c("CASEID", "YYYY"))
attach(Michigan_panel)
y <- cbind(ICS)
X <- cbind(ICE,PX1Q2,RATEX,ZLB,INCOME,AGE,EDUC,MARRY,SEX,AGE_sq)
model1 <- plm(y~X+factor(CASEID)+factor(YEAR), data=Michigan_panel, model="within")
summary(model1)
detach()
```

Adding **factor(CASEID)** and **factor(YEAR)** will add dummy variables in your model.